# I have problem with 'collapse' in the bootstrap's navbar

Tags: vue.js, web, frontend

I'm making a responsive NavBar using bootstrap5 and vue.js.
I made a simple responsive NavBar with an example of bootstrap, but there are some problems when I make some modifications and use 'collapse button'.
The image below is my NavBar. (Desktop UI and mobile UI)

[image]

[image]

And this is the image when I open the menu bar through collapse.
When I open the menu, the logo and login button on the right are pushed aside. (The login button goes down the menu bar)

[image]

And this is my code.

```
<div class="container-fluid container-lg px-0 px-xl-5">
    <header class="mb-3" :class="{ 'navbar--hidden': !showNavbar }">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top navbar-light">
        <div class="container-fluid container-md mx-0 mx-md-auto bg-white">
          <button
            class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
            aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="logo-font fs-4" href="/"> LOGO </a>
          <!-- menu items -->
          <div
            class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center"
            id="navbarNavAltMarkup"
          >
            <div class="navbar-nav text-start">
              <a class="nav-item" href="screen1">menu1</a>
              <a class="nav-item" href="screen1">menu2</a>
              <a class="nav-item" href="screen1">menu3</a>
              <a class="nav-item" href="screen1">menu4</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="nav-login" href="login">login</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div>
```

May I know the cause and solution of this problem?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you may duplicate the login button and put it in front of the menu items div like so:

```
    <div class="container-fluid container-md mx-0 mx-md-auto bg-white">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="logo-font fs-4" href="/"> LOGO </a>
      <a class="nav-login d-sm-none" href="login">login</a>
      <!-- menu items -->
      <div class="collapse show navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavAltMarkup"> 
        <div class="navbar-nav text-start">
          <a class="nav-item" href="screen1">menu1</a>
          <a class="nav-item" href="screen1">menu2</a>
          <a class="nav-item" href="screen1">menu3</a>
          <a class="nav-item" href="screen1">menu4</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="nav-login d-xs-none" href="login">login</a>
    </div>
```

Then, you can play around with the [bootstrap hiding element class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements) to control when to show/hide the login buttons.

I hope this idea will be helpful for you, if not, perhaps you may provide a sample snippet so that we can understand more about your problem.

Comment: Oh, there was a way to apply size and display-none. Thank you!